# Parameter for razor page handler method always getting the same value

Tags: c#, razor

I have a razor page that displays a collection of entities in a table.  There's a delete button with a named handler method that is supposed to delete the item from the collection by it's Id.  The problem is no matter what row I hit delete on the top Log/row always gets removed.  When I put a break point to debug on the handler method, the value of the LogId parameter is always the same(the Id of the Log at the top of the table).

.cshtml

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Client.Logs.ToList())
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrnType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrnDte)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrnAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="@item.LogId" />
            <input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" asp-page-handler="DeleteTransaction" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

.cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteTransactionAsync(int? LogId)
{
    //LogId always has the value of the Id from the first Log in the table
    //Delete log
}
```

Comment: So, when there are 100 rows in the table, with 100 hidden input fields named LogId, and 100 delete buttons, how would the code know which one to get? Just because your delete button is close to the input field? That would be strange. You need to have a property on your delete button `asp-route-id="@item.LogId"` for example so your button can send the correct ID to the controller action.

Comment: @Dennis1679 The handler method parameter should know which value to get because I thought the parameter name must match a form field name for it to be automatically bound to the value.  In my case value=@item.LogId

Comment: My input form field has a name of LogId and my parameter for my handler method is named LogId.  My input form field is rendering with the name LogId and the correct distinct LogId value for the value="" attribute.   However when I hit my break point my parameter value is always the first LogId.

Comment: forget about the value attribute. You need to add asp-route-id="@item.LogId" to the input like this  `<input onclick="" type="" class="" asp-page-handler="" asp-route-id="@item.LogId" value="" />`

Comment: @Dennis1679 I removed the hidden input and added the asp-route-id and it works.  However you can pass parameters to handler methods via form inputs and routing... https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/  I know it works, but I wonder why passing my parameter via input didn't work

Comment: I already explained it :) Because there is nothing unique between each `<input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="@item.LogId" />`. They all have the same name value.

Comment: @Dennis1679  But they are unique...  the get rendered as <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="2" /> etc...  They have unique name,value pairs...  they are not rendered as value="@item.LogId"

Comment: How are those names unique? ;) They are both named LogId. Look at my code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a visual example.

Say your Model.Client.Logs contains 2 items.

```cs
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Client.Logs.ToList())
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="@item.LogId" />
            <input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" asp-page-handler="DeleteTransaction" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

The result of this would output

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- First element named "LogId" -->
        <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="123" />
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="DeleteTransaction" name="LogId" value="Delete" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <!-- Second element named "LogId" -->
        <input type="hidden" name="LogId" value="456" />
        <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="DeleteTransaction" name="LogId" value="Delete" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

You click on delete on the second row.
Now the pagehandler method will look for an html element with the name of LogId to take its value.

*But* there are **2** elements with the name *LogId* (not counting the delete buttons).

The handler goes through your DOM, line by line until it discovers it has found what it was looking for. The first element named LogId. Great, now it can stop looking.

It has found the value and it returns it to the action. That's why your code doesn't work and why it's returning the first value it finds, because it isn't aware that there are actually more items named LogId. And even then, it wouldn't know which one you selected.

Comment: adding <input onclick="" type="" class="" asp-page-handler="" asp-route-LogId="@item.LogId" value="" /> and removing the hidden input worked.  the name appended to asp-route- needs to be the same name as the parameter in your handler method.